# How to make a simple deck of magical cards that will be drawn randomly?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, roll20

Sorry if the question was asked before, but I didn't find any good answers for me.

Im a new DM playing on Roll20 and I'm making a new Class that fights with magical cards, dice and coins.

#### Constraints/Objectives

I need a deck of cards that you can drawn from, where all cards have different effects. But I'm not sure how to make it very efficient, because some cards in the deck are duplicates.

Also, if you draw a card, its gone from the deck. But you should also be able to "reshuffle" the deck to put all cards back into the deck.  I thought about making a rollable table on roll 20, but from what I know, you can't make a setting to get an event only once before having to "reset" the table.

**Is there a better method than just writing all cards already drawn somewhere, and let the player roll the table until he gets a new card?**

Comment: Do you have the subscription membership or the free membership?  I ask because there are some scripts that require the subscription level of membership. (And I think someone has a deck similar to that, but I'd need to take a longer look at the roll20 help/wiki before I can find it) ...

Comment: I use a free account for roll20. I might ask the player to make a rollable table with that script (if it is even possible).

Comment: Hi Aleksandar and welcome to the RPGSE! Have you read the [help guide on cards](https://wiki.roll20.net/Cards) from the Roll20 wiki on cards? It sounds like you might not be familiar with the discard and recall features.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt know you can make that many customization for the card decks.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @Rykara: Sounds like the starting point for a good answer. :)

Answer (score 15):

Roll20 already provides a deck of regular playing cards. As provided in a comment by Rykara, here is some basic info about the [regular deck](https://wiki.roll20.net/Cards).

If the default deck is not suitable for you then there is always the modifiable [collections: card decks](https://wiki.roll20.net/Collections#Card_Decks).